# How to extend my root and home partition?

Tags: partitioning

I want to use the total space of sda2 to extend the size of sda6. I did go through the already asked questions.But the answers did not work.Deleted sda2 but could not find the move/resize option for sda3. And  no additional space could be given to sda6.Can anyone help me please?
[This is the current Gparted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ0OL.png)

Comment: You can't resize the logical partition sda3 while it's subpartitions are in use.  Boot to a LiveUSB or LiveCD environment, unmount all partitions, then try and resize.

Comment: Before you move/resize sda6, you might consider if you really want sda4 and sda5 to consume so much free space. Your hard disk is kind of smallish, and space is a premium. Can they be combined, and/or be reduced in size? Tell me what you want and I can outline the exact steps for you. And you're sure you don't want/need Windows OS? Please update your screenshot with the current status.

Comment: I have data in sda4 and 5 and can't back them up at this moment.I surely don't need windows anymore.

Comment: You may want Windows to do BIOS updates, or run some apps for which there is no equivalent on Ubuntu. NTFS partitions are nice because they can be shared between Windows and Ubuntu. Can we reduce sda4/5, and/or combine them? There's so much wasted space there. Let me know what you want to do. ps: please remove the two screenshots and re-add a current screenshot

Comment: My windows actually crushed recently . I have no problem in combining those partitions other than the fact that I have important data on them. I  have no mean to back them up right now.Is there ways to install windows without harming the ubuntu and dual boot situation?